# How to verify email when user successfully registered in laravel-8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I developed two API's register and login ,now i want to develop a verification email when user registered successfully ,the registered user gets an email for verification for this i developed one function i am not getting any email when user registered i am unable to find where did i mistake please helpme to fix this issue
`UserController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use App\Models\PasswordReset;
use App\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'fullName'=>'required|string|between:3,15',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|regex:/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$/',
            'mobile'=>'required|digits:10'
            ]);
        $user = new User([
            'fullName'=> $request->input('fullName'),
            'email'=> $request->input('email'),
            'password'=> bcrypt($request->input('password')),
            'mobile'=>$request->input('mobile')           
        ]);
        $user->save();
        $input["created_at"] = now();
        $input['verifytoken'] =Str::random(60);
        // User::create($request->getAttributes())->sendEmailVericationNotification();
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Successfully Created user'],201);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid Credentials'], 401);
            }
        }catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Could not create token'],500);
        }
        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
    }

    public function verifyEmail()
    {
        $id = request('id');
        $token = request('token');
        $user = User::where("verifytoken", $token)->first();
        // $user = User::where("email", $email)->first();
        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json(['message' => "Not a Registered Email"], 200);
        } else if ($user->email_verified_at === null) {
            $user->email_verified_at = now();
            $user->save();
            return response()->json(['message' => "Email Successfully Verified"], 201);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => "Email Already Verified"], 202);
        }
    }
}
```

`User.php[user-model]`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use App\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject,MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'fullName',
        'email',
        'password',
        'mobile',
        'verifytoken'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims() {
        return [];
    }
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
}
```

`User migration table`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('fullName');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('mobile')->unique();
            $table->string('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('verifytoken')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');

    }
}
```

`VerificationMail.php[it's under Notifications]`

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class VerificationMail extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $email;
    public $token;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(string $email, string $token)
    {
        //
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $url = "/api/verifyemail/$this->token"; 

        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('Welcome to BookStore, I am Aman Verma')
                    ->line('Please Verify your email to get started with us')
                    ->action('Verification Email', url($url))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

`api.php`

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/login', [UserController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/register', [UserController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('verifyemail/{token}','VerificationController@verifyEmail');
    Route::post('/sendPasswordResetLink', 'App\Http\Controllers\PasswordResetRequestController@forgotPassword');
    Route::post('/resetPassword', 'App\Http\Controllers\ChangePasswordController@resetPassword');
    Route::get('/email/verify/{id}',[VerificationController::class,'verify']);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your user model, you will need to override this built in function from the MustVerifyEmail.php trait.

```
// User.php
...

/**
 * Send the email verification notification.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    //replace with your verification email
    $this->notify(new VerifyEmail);
}
```